# Why I cant search location in below lollipop version?

Tags: android

i have a problem while loading map in lollipop version  i cant get location while i search in map. it showing no location found, but it works in above marsmallow version.i dont know what mistake i have done.pls anyone give a solution to find out.

```
  Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, locationListener);

     currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    //currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (currentLocation != null) {

        current = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        //get location details
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(current.latitude, current.longitude, 1);
            Log.e(TAG, "addresses: "+addresses );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            addr = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        }
        CurrMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(current).title("Current Position").snippet(addr));

        addCameraToMap(current);
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "UnAvailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Check my answer below .

Answer (score 1):

Add following permission in AndroidManifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First Add Permission to your Manifest file:
After Permission added to your Manifest:

```
int permissionPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission("Your Activity Name", 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                int permissionPhoneState1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission("Your Activity Name", Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
                if ((permissionPhoneState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (permissionPhoneState1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    location(location);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions("Your Activity Name", new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);
                }

  private void location(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        location.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
        location.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
        final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
     }
  }
```

Hope this one help you

Comment: runtime permissions are required on or above android M. In lollipop there were no dynamic permissions

Answer (score 0):

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()` is an Asynchronous call you are using `currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);` which might not have received your current location yet as async call might not have been completed.  Make sure you are using `onLocationChanged()` callback to get your location.